# Nodejs forever pm

Tags: node.js, forever

I am using a forever PM for my nodejs API.

I'm getting the following error while i try to start the app using forever.

warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms

info:    Forever processing file: hello.js

error:   Cannot start forever

error:   log file /home/user/.forever/forever.log exists. Use the -a or --append option to append log.
user@testub002:~$

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your problem is that you need to either delete `/home/user/.forever/forever.log` each time you run forever or execute `forever -a hello.js`

Comment: or use the `--append` option :)